# Need an algorithm written for delay time calculation

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, signal-processing, core-audio

Lets say we have a variable x (Sample rate) and will make 4 delay times (in samples) that have ratios of 1:1.5 for parallel comb filtering. in the example below the comb filter times differ from 30 to 45 milliseconds.
x/1000 = a
a*30 = i
a*35 = j
a*40 = k
a*45 = n
the first number i should be rounded up to the closest integer. the second number j should be rounded up to an integer that does not have any common factors with i, and k should be rounded up to an integer that does not have any common factor with both i and j and so on. So I am looking for an algorithm that would round up all the numbers j, k, and n to have no common divisors with i.

The real problem we have is not finding a straightforward way to find common NONE divisors of two numbers, as when you google this results are all explanation of common divisors etc... If someone could explain just that bit the rest is piece of cake anyway.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: whoever downvoted this, please explain why

Comment: I presume these numbers are small enough that factoring them is not difficult. So fining the greatest common divisor of two numbers is not difficult. So you can just increment j until it has no common factors with i, then increment k until it has no common factors with i or j, and so on. What's the problem?

Comment: The downvotes are there because you are asking us to write you an algorithm and show zero effort of doing it yourself.

Comment: Sorry I asked this for an audio engineer friend, he was trying hard and if you read it he asked for help for "none divisors of two numbers" bit of the algorithm, not the whole thing, so it's a bit harsh comment in my opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply compute the next prime number for each, which will likely be faster than trying to find some arbitrary number that has no common factors. I don't know what the scale `x` is in your application, but if it's reasonably small then computing the next prime number three times takes almost no time.

There are only 78,500 prime numbers between 0 and 1,000,000. You could easily generate all of those and store them in a table. Then, given some value, a binary search will give you the next prime number larger than that value. So if you never expect `a*45` to be larger than 1,000,000, you can have a very quick way to get the next number. Granted, it costs a little memory to store the prime numbers.

Or, you can generate all the primes from 0 up to the one after a*45. Doing so takes a little time, but if you don't have to do this very often it's probably a perfectly acceptable solution. Especially if the processing that you're going to do afterwards is a lot more expensive than computing a few prime numbers.

See [Optimizing the wrong thing](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/10/16/optimizing-the-wrong-thing/) for a little more info.